# Notepadqq: how to exit the full screen mode?

Tags: linux

[Notepadqq](http://notepadqq.altervista.org/wp/) is a Linux source editor.

How to exit the full screen mode on Notepadqq?

Terminating the process which opened Notepadqq and launching the later one again does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any member facing this problem in the future:

I found there is no pre-built keyboard shortcut to exit the full screen mode on Notepadqq.

However you can overcome it by using this simple trick: press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> then uncheck ***Full Screen***.

Comment: Whew!  Works for Geany, too!

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of Notepadqq use 'F11' to switch to/from the Full Screen mode.